# GetKeyboardType(): получить тип клавиатуры и количество клавиш?

Tags: c++

Необходимо получить тип и количество клавиш клавиатуры, делаю это таким образом:

```
  int keyboard_type = GetKeyboardType(0);
  int keyboard_buttons = GetKeyboardType(2);
  cout<< "Type:"<< keyboard_type<<"\n";
  cout<<"Buttons:"<< keyboard_buttons<<"\n";
```

Заголовочный файл `#include <Winuser.h>`
Но при выходе данных я получаю:

```
Type: 7
Buttons: 12
```

В чем проблема? Как бы на клавиатуре явно больше кнопок. Как это исправить?

Comment: Флажок 2 возвращает количество функциональных клавиш (F1 F2 и т.д.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно использовать [RawInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645536(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
#include <Windows.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>

int main()
{
    // Получаем количество устройств.
    ::UINT devices_count{};
    ::GetRawInputDeviceList(nullptr, &devices_count, sizeof(::RAWINPUTDEVICELIST));
    if(0 == devices_count)
    {
        exit(1);
    }
    // Получаем записи устройств.
    auto const p_devices{::std::make_unique<::RAWINPUTDEVICELIST[]>(devices_count)};
    if(static_cast<::UINT>(-1) == ::GetRawInputDeviceList(p_devices.get(), &devices_count, sizeof(::RAWINPUTDEVICELIST)))
    {
        exit(1);
    }
    // Пробегаемся по устройствам и получаем информацию об клавиатуро-подобных устройствах.
    ::UINT device_index{};
    for(device_index = 0; devices_count != device_index; ++device_index)
    {
        auto const & device_entry{p_devices[device_index]};
        if(RIM_TYPEKEYBOARD == device_entry.dwType)
        {
            // Получаем имя устройства.
            ::WCHAR device_name[256]{};
            ::UINT device_name_chars_count{::std::size(device_name)};
            auto const chars_written{::GetRawInputDeviceInfoW(device_entry.hDevice, RIDI_DEVICENAME, device_name, &device_name_chars_count)};
            if((0 == chars_written) || (::std::size(device_name) <= chars_written))
            {
                exit(-1);
            }
            device_name[chars_written] = L'\0';
            // Получаем информацию об устройстве, в т.ч. количество клавиш.
            ::RID_DEVICE_INFO info{};
            ::UINT info_bytes_count{sizeof(info)};
            auto const bytes_written{::GetRawInputDeviceInfoW(device_entry.hDevice, RIDI_DEVICEINFO, &info, &info_bytes_count)};
            if(sizeof(info) != bytes_written)
            {
                exit(-1);
            }
            ::std::wcout << device_index << " " << device_name << " keys count " << info.keyboard.dwNumberOfKeysTotal << ::std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Пример вывода:

> 8 \?\HID#VID_046D&PID_C534&MI_00#7&1eb1a69&0&0000#{884b96c3-56ef-11d1-bc8c-00a0c91405dd} keys count 173
>
> 9 \?\HID#VID_045E&PID_00DB&MI_00#7&260a22d8&0&0000#{884b96c3-56ef-11d1-bc8c-00a0c91405dd} keys count 154
>
> 10 \?\HID#VID_18F8&PID_0F97&MI_01&Col01#7&130d9622&0&0000#{884b96c3-56ef-11d1-bc8c-00a0c91405dd} keys count 110